# Unable to mount root fs after loss of power

Tags: data-recovery

I accidentally pulled the power cort of my Computer while it was running. After I turned it on again it said "unable to mount root fs" so I tried to boot an old kernel. It worked and I am now able to save my data at least. What is the most accurate step from this position to repair the system. Reinstall Ubuntu, boot from live CD or any way from the loaded kernel desktop to operate?

UPDATE: the Computer can sometimes not even boot the kernel selection. I guess reinstall Ubuntu is necessary, is there a way to check the hard disk if it took damage?

Comment: It's kind of unclear. You tried once and it didn't boot, then you tried again with a different kernel version and it booted, right? Did you try the newer kernel again? Did you lose any data?